# Regexp on C# not finding all matches of CDATA

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>
```

AND

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I'm using:

```
regex = new Regex(@"\<script(.*)type=(.*)text/javascript(.*)\>(.*)\/\/\<\!\[CDATA\[(?<text>(.*))\/\/\]\]\>(.*)\<\/script\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline); 

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(html))
{

}
```

but it only finds the first match. It doesn't find the second. Can't for the life of me see why?

Comment: Try your regex out here: https://www.debuggex.com  It looks to me like you have a spurious `?` just before `<text>`

Comment: https://regex101.com/ says your regex matches both examples perfectly fine (after removing newlines from the input). While `RegexOptions.Singleline` should fix any problems with newlines, could you remove all newlines from your second example and test if your code matches it afterwards?

Comment: Oh and you did not escape the `/` in `text/javascript` - try `text\/javascript` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is too greedy at the 6th group, ***(.*)***\<\/script\>*. I added lazy behavior to all the `(.*)` groups, and here is a fixed regex:

`(?s)\<script(.*?)type=(.*?)text/javascript(.*?)\>(.*?)\/\/\<\!\[CDATA\[(?<text>(.*?))\/\/\]\]\>(.*?)\<\/script\>`

So, if you run the regex on your concatenated inputs, you will get 2 matches, and your CDATA will be in `.Groups[5].Value`.